# np.meshgrid using up too much ram Google Colab

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I'm working on this assignment for my class and I'm having an issue where Google Colab says that I've used up all the RAM when the np.meshgrid line is executed. I understand the meshgrid is using like 50GB of space but I can't figure out how to reduce that. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong please? This is the question:

[image: Programming Question]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import lines
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# you need to define the min and max values from the data
step_size = 0.05
data, labels = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
(n_samples, n_features), n_digits = data.shape, np.unique(labels).size
reduced_data = PCA(n_components=3).fit_transform(data)
kmeans = KMeans(init="k-means++", n_clusters=n_digits, n_init=4)
kmeans.fit(reduced_data)

x_min, x_max = reduced_data[:, 0].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = reduced_data[:, 1].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 1].max() + 1
z_min, z_max = reduced_data[:, 2].min() - 1, reduced_data[:, 2].max() + 1

# x_min = -32.16990591295523
# x_max = 32.700123434559885
# y_min = -28.49444674444793
# y_max = 31.092205057161326
# z_min = -30.301750160946828
# z_max = 33.70884919881785

xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, step_size),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, step_size),
                         np.arange(z_min, z_max, step_size))

# mesh grid size = 3894
```

Comment: We don't know the parameters to those 3 `np.arange` expressions.  Lets say the 3 resulting arrays each have size `N, M, L`.  Then one `xx` will be (N,M,L) shape, ie. `N*M*L` elements.  times that by 3.  So you should be able to estimate the memory use of that `meshgrid`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the comment. I added the values of the parameters and the size of the `meshgrid` as an edit in the code. I still can't figure out how to fix it though :(

Answer (score 1):

So your 3 `arange` have about the same size

```
In [38]: np.arange(-32,32,.05).shape
Out[38]: (1280,)
```

`meshgrid` makes 3 "cubes" with 1280 points on each dimension

```
In [42]: (1280**3)/1e9
Out[42]: 2.097152
```

That's 2G of points, or 16Gbytes of memory;  time 3 is 50 GB of memory use.

No wonder it's complaining!

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand why it's complaining. Is there a way to reduce the memory impact while passing the same stuff into the `meshgrid`? Like is there a better way I should assign value to `xx`, `yy`, and `zz`?